# pyvisa error: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyvisa

I'm trying to send a command to an instrument using pyvisa - but I'm getting the following error when I run the python script:

> cmd.endswith = 0 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute
>   'endswith'

This following is the code that is receiving the above error:

```
import time
import visa

rm=visa.ResourceManager()
vi=rm.open_resource('ASRL1::INSTR')

cmd = [0xAA,0,0x20,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0xcb]

cmd.endswith = 0
vi.write(cmd)
vi.read()
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of the error effectively?

Comment: What was `cmd.endswith = 0` even intended to do?

Answer (score 1):

The `endswith` function only works for strings. What I think you meant to do was to iterate through your list and check if it endswith 0. This is why you get an error saying that lists have no attribute `endswith`, because they do not. Only strings do.

Also, `endswith` is used by: `listname.endswith(ending)` which returns either True or False.

Hope it helps.